# How can i ignore error in an update query?

Tags: postgresql

I am running an update query like

```
update datavalue 
   set categoryoptioncomboid = '21519' 
 where dataelementid = '577' and 
       categoryoptioncomboid = '471';
```

but it is giving an error

> ```
> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "datavalue_pkey"
> DETAIL:  Key (dataelementid, periodid, sourceid, categoryoptioncomboid, attributeoptioncomboid)=(577, 35538, 10299, 21519, 15) already exists.
> ```

Is there a way to make postgres continue updating and skip any errors? Is there a way without using procedure for loop?

Comment: Have a look at `Merge` https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/23520/sql-merge.html

Comment: `on conflict` is for insert only and `merge` does not exist in PostgreSQL,

Comment: @Tometzky my bad - early morning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

```
update datavalue
set categoryoptioncomboid = '21519' 
where
  dataelementid = '577' and categoryoptioncomboid = '471'
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from datavalue dv
    where dv.dataelementid=datavalue.dataelementid
      and dv.periodid=datavalue.periodid
      and dv.sourceid=datavalue.sourceid
      and dv.categoryoptioncomboid='21519'
      and dv.attributeoptioncomboid=datavalue.attributeoptioncomboid
  );
```

Another idea is to `insert` with `on conflict` and then delete unneeded rows. But it requires knowledge of the full definition of `datavalue` table columns.

Comment: Hi Tometzky, this seems to work but how? What does the clause after not exists mean?

Comment: It just checks if there exists a row that conflicts with the primary key and runs the update only when it does not. The `exists` keyword returns true when the subquery returns any row, so the `1` can be anything, but it is often used by convention.